# How to get in / out spanning tree of a node with readable labels in response with gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

This question is to how get a more readable response from gremlin that can be used to further process the data. I can get the spanning tree with `simplePath` step with some arbitrary depth (10 here) as follows:

`g.V().has(name, foo).repeat(both().simplePath()).emit().times(10).dedup()`
or further break down by in / out:
`g.V().has(name, foo).repeat(in().simplePath()).emit().times(10).dedup()`
`g.V().has(name, foo).repeat(out().simplePath()).emit().times(10).dedup()`

but this returns an array of vertices without clear grouping, for example I can't know, just by getting the response, what are the `in` vertices of an `in` vertex or any other depth.

Is there a way to get a nested response back or clearly label each level and the in / out vertices at those levels in gremlin?

Answer (score 1):

You can use loops() and group().by() to accomplish this.  Example below uses the air-routes dataset from Practical Gremlin.

```
g.V().has('airport', 'code', 'ANC').
      emit().repeat(group('x').by(loops()).by(__.fold()).out().dedup()).times(3).
      cap('x').unfold()
```

This returns:

```
{0: [v[2]]}
{1: [v[3], v[1101], v[1102], v[1103], v[1104], v[1105], v[1106], v[1107], v[1108], v[1109], v[1110], v[1111], v[1112], v[1113], v[1114], v[8], v[11], v[13], v[17], v[18], v[20], v[22], v[23], v[27], v[30], v[31], v[37], v[884], v[886], v[149], v[159], v[1092], v[1093], v[1094], v[1095], v[1096], v[1097], v[1098], v[1099], v[1100], v[2658]]}
{2: [v[368], v[371], v[375], v[389], v[1], v[4], v[5], v[6], v[7], v[9], v[10], v[12], v[15], v[16], v[21], v[24], v[25], v[26], v[28], v[29], v[34], v[35], v[38], v[39], v[41], v[42], v[43], v[45], v[46], v[47], v[49], v[50], v[416], v[430], v[444], v[52], v[99], v[1274], v[136], v[147], v[150], v[549], v[929], v[151], v[178], v[180], v[182], v[183], v[184], v[185], v[186], v[187], v[188], v[189], v[190], v[193], v[194], v[227], v[239], v[240], v[244], v[265], v[268], v[269], v[273], v[278], v[280], v[281], v[2], v[2335], v[2336], v[2338], v[2355], v[2357], v[2365], v[2379], v[3208], v[1283], v[2358], v[2388], v[1771], v[3133], v[2983], v[2618], v[2337], v[2340], v[2350], v[1770], v[3008], v[2333], v[2334], v[2342], v[2346], v[2363], v[2364], v[2368], v[2369], v[2377], v[2381], v[2384], v[2387], v[2874], v[2321], v[2326], v[2331], v[2341], v[2359], v[2366], v[2373], v[2378], v[2386], v[3256], v[3257], v[2320], v[2361], v[2353], v[2383], v[2616], v[2351], v[301], v[305], v[306], v[314], v[356], v[357], v[358], v[359], v[360], v[361], v[362], v[363], v[364], v[365], v[366], v[367], v[369], v[370], v[372], v[373], v[374], v[376], v[377], v[379], v[380], v[381], v[382], v[383], v[384], v[385], v[386], v[387], v[388], v[390], v[391], v[392], v[393], v[394], v[395], v[396], v[397], v[398], v[399], v[400], v[1123], v[1127], v[14], v[19], v[33], v[36], v[40], v[44], v[48], v[401], v[402], v[403], v[404], v[405], v[406], v[407], v[408], v[409], v[410], v[411], v[412], v[413], v[414], v[415], v[417], v[418], v[419], v[420], v[421], v[422], v[423], v[424], v[425], v[426], v[427], v[428], v[429], v[431], v[432], v[441], v[443], v[445], v[51], v[54], v[55], v[58], v[60], v[61], v[64], v[67], v[68], v[70], v[74], v[80], v[83], v[85], v[86], v[865], v[872], v[877], v[883], v[890], v[895], v[2076], v[2082], v[3259], v[106], v[122], v[131], v[132], v[133], v[134], v[135], v[138], v[525], v[530], v[909], v[919], v[921], v[934], v[936], v[941], v[950], v[3306], v[164], v[181], v[195], v[196], v[198], v[563], v[571], v[573], v[575], v[576], v[577], v[580], v[969], v[208], v[211], v[217], v[225], v[237], v[238], v[241], v[243], v[245], v[246], v[603], v[605], v[625], v[629], v[630], v[640], v[3416], v[263], v[264], v[267], v[270], v[271], v[277], v[288], v[289], v[291], v[292], v[295], v[296], v[297], v[300], v[651], v[1082], v[312], v[378], v[1117], v[1118], v[1119], v[1120], v[1121], v[1122], v[1124], v[1125], v[1126], v[435], v[63], v[84], v[899], v[900], v[102], v[161], v[205], v[220], v[223], v[224], v[236], v[608], v[304], v[318], v[337], v[701], v[714], v[837], v[1241], v[53], v[56], v[57], v[66], v[73], v[75], v[76], v[92], v[93], v[100], v[864], v[868], v[870], v[874], v[876], v[878], v[882], v[885], v[887], v[888], v[889], v[891], v[892], v[893], v[894], v[896], v[897], v[898], v[3283], v[103], v[105], v[109], v[140], v[146], v[148], v[901], v[902], v[903], v[907], v[916], v[924], v[177], v[199], v[200], v[567], v[568], v[213], v[215], v[249], v[250], v[638], v[3046], v[3426], v[272], v[294], v[299], v[665], v[669], v[676], v[677], v[307], v[437], v[438], v[439], v[447], v[449], v[450], v[917], v[918], v[938], v[943], v[947], v[949], v[3314], v[3326], v[152], v[153], v[166], v[958], v[961], v[964], v[611], v[613], v[620], v[623], v[632], v[283], v[290], v[293], v[1069], v[1072], v[1073], v[1074], v[1075], v[1076], v[1077], v[1078], v[1079], v[1080], v[1151], v[32], v[434], v[436], v[446], v[448], v[59], v[78], v[79], v[90], v[482], v[1295], v[2074], v[2075], v[3288], v[110], v[112], v[145], v[526], v[527], v[529], v[2107], v[163], v[192], v[956], v[957], v[959], v[960], v[962], v[963], v[965], v[966], v[967], v[968], v[970], v[202], v[242], v[609], v[612], v[615], v[649], v[650], v[3019], v[3439], v[266], v[286], v[652], v[1128], v[1129], v[1534], v[3347], v[951], v[87], v[863], v[1272], v[1273], v[1275], v[1276], v[920], v[866], v[867], v[869], v[871], v[873], v[875], v[107], v[671], v[673], v[1294], v[2073], v[913], v[1050], v[1438], v[282], v[1070], v[1071], v[1661], v[3286], v[3287], v[911], v[912], v[915], v[923], v[926], v[930], v[931], v[932], v[933], v[935], v[937], v[939], v[940], v[944], v[945], v[946], v[948], v[3323], v[952], v[953], v[954], v[955], v[628], v[71], v[458], v[212], v[214], v[639], v[641], v[642], v[643], v[644], v[647], v[648], v[2100], v[2322], v[2323], v[2324], v[2332], v[2347], v[2352], v[2362], v[2367], v[2374], v[2380], v[2389], v[2048], v[2420], v[2934], v[2601], v[3028], v[2325], v[2327], v[2328], v[2329], v[2330], v[2339], v[2345], v[2354], v[2356], v[2360], v[2371], v[2382], v[2385], v[3122], v[2024], v[3258], v[1768], v[1772], v[2621], v[3006], v[3009], v[2370], v[2376], v[2396], v[2343], v[2372], v[3203], v[2313], v[2344], v[2349], v[3236], v[1769], v[710], v[657]]}
```

Comment: I can see that this does provide the levels, but it is missing two types labels (or identifiers) to solve ambiguity:
1. in deeper levels, say level == 2 I can't say who is the parent of a given vertex:  
`A -> B -> C`  
`A -> D-> F`  
I wouldn't know the parent of `F` is `B` or `D`
2. If I run `both()`, I can't separate out the `in` and `out` vertices.

Comment: What I was looking for was the `tree()` step, that would solve the problem:
`g.V().has(name, foo).repeat(both().simplePath()).emit().times(10).dedup().tree()`

Answer (score 0):

with a combination of `.project()` and `tree()` steps.
Something like:

```
g.V().has(name, foo).project('in', 'out').
   by(repeat(in().simplePath()).emit().times(10).dedup().
      tree().by(values(name))).
   by(repeat(out().simplePath()).emit().times(10).dedup().
      tree().by(values(name)))
```